# async/await problem when extend super class

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to set the order of execution of my methods on the constructor of my supper class because i have a multiple class that extends from this supper class and the order is the same on all of them (take advantage of abstract class), but i am facing a strange problem where i get a result of a variable before the finishing of the future, this is a simulation code of my above description, you can try it on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/):

```
abstract class SuperClass {
  bool _success;
  bool get isSuccess => _success;
  set setSuccess(bool success) => this._success = success;
  SuperClass() {
    //checkLogin();
    runCode();
    //sendRequest();
  }
  runCode() async {
    await doSomething();
  }
  Future<void> doSomething();
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  String text;
  @override
  Future<void> doSomething() async {
    text = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => '2 sec of getting data');
    if (text.isNotEmpty) {
      setSuccess = true;
      print(text);
    }
    print('value of success is "$isSuccess" from the overriding method');
  }
}

void main() async {
  SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
  // if (subClass.isSuccess) // how can i get success from the sub class
    // do somthing else
  print('value of success is "${subClass.isSuccess}"');
}
```

the result is :

```
value of success is "null"
2 sec of getting data
value of success is "true" from the overriding method
```

My question is why i get the value of the variable from the super class while i am running the future method before it and read it from the sub class ?

Did i miss something or how i can handle this logic ?

Answer (score 0):

you need another method in the abstract class, when creating an object from the subclass, calling abstract class constructor automatically, you are calling  **"doSomething"** override method in the constructor by **"runCode"** method, but since **"doSomething"** method  is override method It will be called automatically in subclasses, **So you need another method**

Comment: doSomething() is inside runCode() which is another method

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about why you get the print in this order rather than:

```
2 sec of getting data
value of success is "true" from the overriding method
value of success is "true"
```

that is just because you call the `async` function `runCode()` in the constructor of `SuperClass` which is implicitly called when you create a `SubClass` as the latter inherits from the former. Since the method is `async` and you are not `await`int it, the method starts running on a different thread and code execution is not stoped there waiting for the `runCode()` method to return.

This means that `runCode()` starts executing in a different thread and immediately after that, the `SuperClass` constructor returns, the `SubClass` method (which implicitly called the former) also returns, and then your print statement from main executes. Since these steps take less than two seconds to execute, they finish executing before the rest of `runCode()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can remove the `runCode()` from the abstract class constructor and call the `doSomething()` method after initializing:

```
void main() async {
  SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
  await subClass.doSomething();
  print('value of success is "${subClass.isSuccess}"');
}
```